# Conflicting styles from cellStyle and rowStyle in ag-Grid

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am just wondering if there is a conflict between cellStyle and rowStyle in ag-Grid, which will win?

I have seen situations cellStyle wins but there are also situations rowStyle wins. I am kind of confused.

Answer (score 1):

CellStyle wins. Check this plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/0FsGwddhbdYVdzEA

So the precedence will be in below sequence - in ascending order

```
   1. Row Style
   2. Column Style
   3. Cell Style
```

Comment: In my code, for some reasons if the conflicting style is 'color' then Cell Style wins but if the conflicting style is border then Row Style wins

Comment: I need to define columns identation like `rowStyle: 'numericColumn'` to align both cell value and header to the right. Also I need to define a class to cells (to apply a CSS rule), How can I recreate the `numericColumn` alignment using Cell Style?